# Exception with GatherBy: gathering complex conjugates

Tags: list-manipulation, complex, gathering

I want to gather the complex-conjugates that are in a list, but with an exception: only if the imaginary part isn't zero.

For example:

```
poly = 2 - 2 x - x^2 + x^4
roots = x /. Solve[poly == 0, x]
GatherBy[roots, {Re[#], Abs[Im[#]]} &]
```

Gives:

```
{{-1 - i, -1 + i}, {1, 1}}
```

So here indeed the conjugates -1-i and -1+i are combined, which is what I want. But that also happens for 1 and 1, which I don't want to happen because there is no imaginary part.

So the desired output is:

```
{{-1 - i, -1 + i}, {1}, {1}}
```

And this idea should work with any polynomial, not only with this specific example.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you care about the order?

Comment: @Kuba No, as long as the complex-conjugates are gathered together.

Comment: Dirty trick `GatherBy[roots, {Re@#, 
   If[# == 0, RandomReal[{0, 1}], #] &@Abs@Im@#} &]`

Comment: @belisariusisforth Thank you! Maybe it can also be done in a more elegant way?

Comment: Not really sure if this could be considered "more elegant" `ClearAll[f];
f[0] := RandomReal[{0, 1}];
GatherBy[roots, {Re@#, f@Abs@Im@#} &]`

Comment: @belisariusisforth With your solution, there is a very small chance that two random numbers happen to be equal...

Comment: I don't think so, but perhaps that makes a good question :)

Comment: Did you look at the code I provided in one of your previous questions? I demonstrated there how you might use `GatherBy[]` for this question of yours...

Comment: @J.M. Yes I did, thanks. The problem with your solution was (if I remember correctly) that it gathered all complex factors together, while I only want the conjugates together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elegant this may not be, but it does not rely on uniquely generate symbols / numbers. Using the OP's definitions:

```
Join[
  GatherBy[Cases[roots, n_ /; Im[n] != 0], {Re[#], Abs@Im[#]} &],
  DeleteCases[roots, n_ /; Im[n] != 0]
] /. n_ /; Im[n] == 0 -> {n}

(* Out: {{-1 - I, -1 + I}, {1}, {1}} *)
```

Comment: `Complement[]` should allow for not having to apply tests to the same list twice.

Answer (score 3):

Until someone comes out with an elegant one:

```
ClearAll[f]; 
f[0] := RandomReal[{0, 1}]
GatherBy[roots, {Re@#, f@Abs@Im@#} &]

(* {{-1 - I, -1 + I}, {1}, {1}} *)
```

Comment: `f[0] := Unique[x]` :)

Comment: @Kuba but that one will define a new symbol name at each invocation potentially resulting in memory problems ...

Comment: Add `Temporary` attribute :P Yes I know it's not great but it wasn't my intention :)